# File uploading and processing in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, plupload, uploading

I'm need to implement next page:

User click on button Upload file, select file and uploading it on server. After uploading file will be processed by converter. Converter can return percentage of conversion. How to implement continuous progress bar on page (progress = upload progress + convert progress)?

I'm using PlUpload - this tool can return percentage of uploading file to server, but I can't override returning percentage.

That my upload action:

```
   public ActionResult ConferenceAttachment(int? chunk, string name, Identity cid)
    {
        var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

        var tempfolder = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace('.', '-');
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempfolder);
        var fn = Path.Combine(tempfolder, name);

        chunk = chunk ?? 0;
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fn, chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        // CONVERTING ....

        return Content("OK", "text/plain");
    }
```

Which architecture solution can solve my problem? Or which JS upload library?

Comment: Do you really use chunking feature of plupload ? (is a 30mb file uploaded in say 60 chunks of 500kb ?) If so, when does the conversion happen ? Upon receiving each chunk ? If so, your code seems fine, and just return a json result like this  {"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null}

Comment: I need to compose single progress bar from progress of uploading and progress of converting. At first all file uploads, then converting.

Comment: do you really need the whole file to start your conversion ?

Comment: Yes, as I sad before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use some kind of `Real-Time` connection or a `Streaming` to do this.

1) Using **SignalR** you can create a `Hub` to notificate the client about the progress, easy to implement and powerfull.

[Learn About ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

2) You can adapte this example about `PushStreamContent` to send the progress while you are converting:

[Asynchronously streaming video with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set buffer size as much as you want. But, I would say to upload 8kb data of file at a time & meanwhile start streaming conversion process asynchronously. But, for smooth progress again what kind of file you wanna upload?

Comment: Different files (from 10kb to 30 mb). Converting can take from 1 sec to 5 minutes.

Comment: I think what I said earlier may work properly in your case. But might be different in video,etc. files conversions